# There isn’t anything to compare. master and new_remote_branch_name are entirely different commit histories

Tags: git, github

I created a project using GitHub and created a pull request from branch to master

It is necessary to change Auther of git in the middle, and pull request closes when changing and hitting `git push -f` command
I tried to open again

There is n’t anything to compare.master and new_remote_branch_name are entirely different commit histories.

It would be helpful if this error occurred and someone can tell me the solution

As a trial

```
git commit --allow-empty
git push
```

If you can't solve this and know other solutions, it would be helpful to let me know

Thank you.